# How can I change IP address of previously configured ODI12c(12.2.1.2.6) agent

Tags: oracle, etl

I have installed and configured ODI12c(12.2.1.2.6) in AIX 7.2 server.
Recently, I have changed the IP address of ODI server because of Network Policy. After changed the IP address of AIX7.2 server ODI client can not connect with ODI server. So, How can I change the IP address of previously configured ODI Agent?

The following are the stack trace.

```
oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.InvocationException: ODI-1424: Agent host or port cannot be reached using http://********:20910/oraclediagent.
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.reThrowAgentErrorAsInvocation(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:1716)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:450)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.support.InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(InternalRemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:162)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:614)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invokeIsAlive(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:592)
    at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.testOdiAgent(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:85)
    at oracle.odi.ui.action.SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.actionPerformed(SnpsPopupActionTestAgentHandler.java:76)
    at com.sunopsis.graphical.frame.edit.EditFrameSnpAgent$5.performAction(EditFrameSnpAgent.java:637)
    at oracle.odi.ui.framework.event.OdiActionListener.actionPerformed(OdiActionListener.java:69)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: ODI-1424: Agent host or port cannot be reached using http://*******:20910/oraclediagent.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.invocation.RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.invoke(RemoteRuntimeAgentInvoker.java:451)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: Browse the following location:
$ODI_HOME/user_projects/domains/base_domain/config/fmwconfig/components

Step 2: Modify the system-comp-config.xml with your new ip address

Step 3: Restart ODI Component(startComponent) with ODI agent